# Task blocks UI from refreshing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, task-parallel-library

I am building a WPF application that converts a powerpoint to WPF elements when you select one from a list.
I am using MVVM light to bind a ViewModel to my view and to add communication between ViewModels.

I have two views: OpenLocalView and PresentationView. When I select a powerpoint in the OpenLocalView, a message will be sent by MVVM light to the ViewModel of PresentationView and the MainViewModel with the path to that powerpoint. The MainViewModel switches the view to the PresentationView, and the PresentationViewModel executes this code to convert the powerpoint, and when that is finished, set the current slide so it is shown in the PresentationView:

```
  public void StartPresentation(string location)
  {
        var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        Loading = true;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var converterFactory = new ConverterFactory();
                var converter = converterFactory.CreatePowerPointConverter();
                _slides = converter.Convert(location).Slides;
            }, 
            CancellationToken.None, 
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
            scheduler).ContinueWith(x =>
                {
                    Loading = false;
                    CurrentSlide = _slides.First();
                }, 
                CancellationToken.None, 
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, 
                scheduler);
   }
```

When the Loading property is set, the view gets updated with a "loading" message, to make the UI more responsive:

```
    public Boolean Loading
    {
        get { return _loading; }
        set
        {
            _loading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Loading");
        }
    }
```

The problem is, this executes properly the first time when I load a powerpoint: The view switches to the PresentationView, the "loading" message is displayed, and after the converting is finished, the message disappears and the slide is shown. But when I go back to the OpenLocalView, and choose another powerpoint, the OpenLocalView hangs and it switches to the PresentationView after the converter is finished, not showing the "loading" message at all.

For reference, I will add some more relevant code.

This is executed when a powerpoint is selected in the OpenLocalViewModel:

```
    private void PerformOpenPresentation(string location)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send<OpenPowerPointMessage>(new OpenPowerPointMessage {Location = location});
    }
```

The MainViewModel is subscribed to the messenger and switches the view:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<OpenPowerPointMessage>(this,
            delegate
            {
                if (_presentation == null) _presentation = new PresentationView();
                CurrentView = _presentation;
            });
```

The PresentationViewModel is subscribed to the messenger as well and executes the method shown above:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<OpenPowerPointMessage>(this, message => StartPresentation(message.Location));
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Again, it executes fine one time, then after that not anymore, although the same code is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the UI isn't updated yet when you already start converting. Try waiting a few milliseconds between setting the Loading to true and the start of the converter thread :)

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

```
 var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
 Loading = true;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var converterFactory = new ConverterFactory();
            var converter = converterFactory.CreatePowerPointConverter();
            _slides = converter.Convert(location).Slides;
        }, 
        CancellationToken.None, 
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
here  ----> scheduler).ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                Loading = false;
                CurrentSlide = _slides.First();
            }, 
            CancellationToken.None, 
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, 
            scheduler);
```

You're starting the 'long running' task on the synchronization context, that is - on the UI thread.
Get rid of the scheduler in the long running task, leave it on continuation. :)

Comment: Then I get an exception: "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.". This is because in the converter, I am creating WPF elements.

Comment: @Hanz Well, I have no better idea, since you create UI elements, you can't create them in other thread, you have to do it on the UI thread - but that also means the UI will stay unresponsive for the time of creation. I usually just prepare the loads of data in the background, then bind it to UI on continuation, that allows for higher responsiveness. It may not be viable in your case, but it's hard for me to say now what would be the best solution.

Comment: @Doctor I can live with the fact that the UI is unresponsive while it is converting, but I just want to show the "loading" message before the converting is started, and remove it afterwards. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Hanz Well then, you can just do this sequentially, without tasks. Set your (probably bound `DependencyProperty`) `Loading` to `true`, call the preparation, then change it to `false`. I can't say or guarantee what the result will be, but that sounds like the simplest solution. :)

Comment: Then the OpenLocalView freezes, and after the converting is done, it changes to the PresentationView with the presentation opened. No "loading" message or anything. Could this have something to do with the order in which the subscribers to the message execute their methods?

Comment: @Hanz Possibly, but I can't tell for sure. Maybe someone else will give you a definite answer, I'm out of ideas (or maybe I'm just tired :) ). Good luck tho'.

Comment: It sounds like the task runs and completes before anybody processes the messages to change views and display the loading message. Last time I had a problem like this I had to set things up so that the actual processing was chained off the back off the view switch, so it couldn't even start until the view had been properly updated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving the "Loading = true" in to task start block.. but make sure to use dispatcher  while setting "Loading" value. i may not give the actual reason for the problem but its worth a try...

something like this may help..

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
               System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
                 {
                     Loading = true;
                  });
                var converterFactory = new ConverterFactory();
                var converter = converterFactory.CreatePowerPointConverter();
                _slides = converter.Convert(location).Slides;
            }
```

Comment: Then the OpenLocalView freezes, and after the converting is done, it changes to the PresentationView with the presentation opened. No "loading" message or anything...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it with windows forms, but I think is the same

I create a Label in the Task thread and call the Invoke of the form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AddControl(Control control)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<Control>(AddControl), new object[] { control });
            return;
        }
        this.Controls.Add(control);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var label = new Label
                {
                    Location = new Point(0, 0),
                    Text = "hola",
                    ForeColor = Color.Black
                };
                this.Invoke(new Action<Control>(AddControl), new object[] { label });
            });
    }
}
```

*EDIT*

Ok how about using Dispather.Invoke I'm not sure if this is going to block the UI....

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AddControl()
    {
        var l = new Label
        {
            Content = "Label",
            Height = 28,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            Margin = new Thickness(209, 118, 0, 0),
            Name = "label1",
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top
        };

        Grid.Children.Add(l);
    }


    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(AddControl), null);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a whole other case when using MVVM and WPF. The vM doesn't have access to the UI controls.